# EAS Build Fails with Malformed root json Error on Local Android Build despite Decoding google-services.json

Tags: react-native, expo

I am encountering an error while trying to build my project locally using eas build -p android --local. The error is Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'. > Malformed root json. I've run the command echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_ANDROID_BASE64 | base64 --decode > ./google-services.json to ensure google-services.json is available, but the build still fails. It's not a firebase project.

Here are my eas.json and app.config.js files for reference:

eas.json

```
Copy code
// eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.0.2",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "node": "18.12.1",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "development",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "development",
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_FILE": "dummy"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "preview",
      "env": {
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_FILE": "dummy"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "node": "18.12.1",
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_FILE": "dummy"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "../../local_key/a.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

// app.config.js

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
const IS_DEV = process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'development'

export default {
  expo: {
    name: IS_DEV ? 'a Dev' : 'a',
    slug: 'a',
    scheme: 'a',
    version: '1.0.1',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/splash.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: 'sdkVersion'
    },
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: [
      '**/*'
    ],
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: 'a'
      }
    },
    owner: 'a',
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: IS_DEV ? 'adev' : 'dev.a',
      config: {
        googleMapsApiKey: IS_DEV ? 'a'
      },
      associatedDomains: ['applinks:a.dev'],
      buildNumber: dayjs().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm')
    },
    android: {
      package: IS_DEV ? 'a.dev' : 'a.dev.a',
      googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/splash.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
      },
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: IS_DEV ? 'a'
        }
      },
      intentFilters: [
        {
          action: 'VIEW',
          autoVerify: true,
          data: [
            {
              scheme: 'https',
              host: 'a.dev',
              pathPrefix: '/a'
            }
          ],
          category: ['BROWSABLE', 'DEFAULT']
        }
      ]
    },
    web: {
      favicon: './assets/favicon.png'
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        '@stripe/stripe-react-native',
        {
          merchantIdentifier: '',
          enableGooglePay: false
        }
      ]
    ],
    updates: {
      url: 'https://u.expo.dev/1'
    },
    jsEngine: 'hermes'
  }
}
```

I have followed the EAS documentation to set a dummy value for GOOGLE_SERVICES_FILE in eas.json to suppress the warning about the file not being checked into the repository. Despite ensuring the google-services.json file is correctly decoded and placed in the project directory before building, the error persists. Any help on this would be appreciated!